# How can I acces/download files from the Quectel BG96 using FILE AT commads?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, lte, quectel

Im using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with the Sixfab Raspberry Pi Cellular IoT HAT – LTE-M & NB-IoT & eGPRS. This hat is using the BG96 and I'm using its LTE_M. Im not using a library and making all the functions based on the Datasheets, but im stuck now. Its probably because i don't really understand the [Datasheet about file handling](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/QuectelBG96FILEATCommandsManualV10.35619675/view).

So I'm making a python program that is supposed to download files from AWS S3. Im already able to get the file using:

```
AT+QHTTPGET=60
```

And im saving it to a file for example "sample.zip" using,

```
AT+QHTTPREADFILE="sample.zip",60
```

I can confirm that the file is downloaded successfully by using

```
AT+QFLST
```

command to see list of files is the UFS. The file sample.zip is shown and has the exact same filesize.

I know i can just use AT+QHTTPREAD, but this only works for strings like json or txt. I want to download different types of data.

My question is, how can I access or get this file? The file is saved in the Quectel BG96 UFS, but I want to save it to a file on my Raspberry PI. I tried the download command using

```
AT+QFDWL="sample.zip"
```

but then it just tries to return it as a string which ofcourse can't be done so it will be random characters.

Answer (score 0):

`AT+QFDWL="sample.zip"` should be the correct command.

The modem switches to binary data mode, and prints out the data that represents your zip file. You need to convert the "string" (which is binary data that represents the zip file) you're getting back to binary data and to a file in python.